# Pandas: Groupby and drop rows in each group based on conditon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transform

I have a dataframe:

```
   Name  StartPoint  EndPoint  isDelivered Customer
0     A           1         4            0       C1
1     A           1         4            0       C1
2     A           2         5            1       C1
3     A           3         5            0       C1
4     A           3         6            0       C1
5     A           3         6            1       C1
6     B           1         4            0       C2
7     B           1         4            0       C2
8     B           2         5            1       C2
9     B           3         5            1       C2
10    B           3         6            1       C2
11    B           3         8            0       C2
12    B           3         8            1       C2
```

I want to group by `Name` and each group should have rows that satisfies the following conditions:

1. Minimum value in column `StartPoint`
2. Maximum value in column `EndPoint` and value 1 in column `isDelivered`

This is what I have done:

```
groups = df.groupby(['Name']).StartPoint
groups1 = df.groupby(['Name']).EndPoint
min_StartPoint = groups.transform(min)
max_EndPoint = groups1.transform(max)
df1 = df[(df.StartPoint==min_StartPoint)|(df.EndPoint==max_EndPoint)]
```

The result obtained is:

```
   Name  StartPoint  EndPoint  isDelivered Customer
0     A           1         4            0       C1
1     A           1         4            0       C1
4     A           3         6            0       C1
5     A           3         6            1       C1
6     B           1         4            0       C2
7     B           1         4            0       C2
11    B           3         8            0       C2
12    B           3         8            1       C2
```

But the rows 4 and 11 do not have value 1 in `isDelivered` and hence they are not satisfying the second condition.

My desired result is:

```
   Name  StartPoint  EndPoint  isDelivered Customer
0     A           1         4            0       C1 # Min value in StartPoint
1     A           1         4            0       C1 # Min value in StartPoint
5     A           3         6            1       C1 # Max value in EndPoint and 1 in isDelivered
6     B           1         4            0       C2 # Min value in StartPoint
7     B           1         4            0       C2 # Min value in StartPoint
12    B           3         8            1       C2 # Max value in EndPoint and 1 in isDelivered
```

Is there a way to achieve this using my current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, you just need to add an extra condition to the last line of code:

```
df1 = df[(df.StartPoint==min_StartPoint)|((df.EndPoint==max_EndPoint) 
                                         & (df.isDelivered == 1))]
 
   Name  StartPoint  EndPoint  isDelivered Customer
0     A           1         4            0       C1
1     A           1         4            0       C1
5     A           3         6            1       C1
6     B           1         4            0       C2
7     B           1         4            0       C2
12    B           3         8            1       C2
```

Comment: Omg, I realized I was using the logical 'and' instead of the bitwise '&' and that's why I wasn't getting the result! A dumb mistake from my part. Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You never incorporated both clauses of the second condition.  Make your code reflect the wording as given: the saved rows must match one of the two conditions:

```
df1 = df[(df.StartPoint == min_StartPoint) |
         ((df.EndPoint  == max_EndPoint) & df.isDelivered == 1)]
```

I'd be happy to show you actual output, but you failed to provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a filter to each group:

```
df.groupby(['Name'], group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda g:g[(g.StartPoint == g.StartPoint.min()) |
               ((g.EndPoint == g.EndPoint.max()) & (g.isDelivered == 1))])
```

Output:

```
    Name    StartPoint  EndPoint    isDelivered Customer
0   A       1           4           0           C1
1   A       1           4           0           C1
5   A       3           6           1           C1
6   B       1           4           0           C2
7   B       1           4           0           C2
12  B       3           8           1           C2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realized I was using the logical 'and' instead of the bitwise '&' and that's why I wasn't getting the result. I should have double checked before posting the question.